# MySQL retrieve count of pairs

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two fields: ID_From, ID_To.

Now the fields are populated like this:

```
ID_From    ID_To
  1000      2000           
  2000      1000            
  1000      5000            
  3000      2000            
  4000      3000
  5000      1000
```

What I would like is to query the database the ID of 1000 and then make it return, how many pairs there are. In this case it would return 2. Quering with ID 2000 would return 1. ID 3000 and 4000 would return zero.

Hope I have made it clear enough. Thanks in advance,
Fischer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM myTable a
  JOIN myTable b
    ON a.ID_To = b.ID_From
    AND a.ID_From = b.ID_To
WHERE a.ID_From = 1000 ;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works brilliantly. Have you got any idea how this will scale with many rows?

Comment: @fischer it scales well if there are separate indexes on `ID_To` and `ID_From` for the `JOIN` to use.

Comment: Quite well, if you have indexes on `ID_From` and `ID_To`. You can always try it in your db by populating a test table with random data (1000, 10K, 1M rows) and see how fast it runs.

Comment: It's late and I'm tired but... if (4000, 1000) is added to the demo table, would the expected answer not be 3. Three unique pairs containing 1000... (1000,2000), (1000,5000) and (1000,4000)? This query would not give that answer. Or have I got the wrong end of the stick? Is the OP asking to query solely on ID_From column?

Comment: @Rob: We think he means that to count a pair, it would need both `(4000, 1000)` and `(1000, 4000)` to be in the data.

Comment: @ypercube; Quite right, else he wouldn't expect 3000 and 4000 to yield zero. Time for me to close the laptop I think :)

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) from table_name t1 
join table_name t2 
on t1.ID_from = t2.ID_to
and t1.ID_to = t2.ID_from
where t1.ID_from = 1000
```

Comment: Not seeing the need for a JOIN within the same table here.

Comment: JOIN is the fastest way to find pairs A->B B->A

Answer (score 1):

For `1000`:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM my_table a 
INNER JOIN my_table b ON a.ID_From = b.ID_To
AND b.ID_From = a.ID_To
WHERE a.ID_From = 1000;
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?  The query works with his data.

Comment: You don't need the OR in there.  If it's not in ID_From and ID_To, the join won't have a row for it.

Comment: I did not downvote you. Your query is correct but you don't need the `OR`. You already have the condition `ON a.ID_From = b.ID_To`.

Comment: @Mark & @ypercube, you're correct.  I removed the extraneous `OR`.

Comment: FYI, I didn't downvote you either.  Was going to upvote to correct it but someone beat me to it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE (ID_From >= 1000 AND 1000 <= ID_To) OR (ID_To >= 1000 AND 1000 <= ID_From);
```

Comment: +1. But I think `OR ... ` is redundant. From my understanding `ID_TO` must be greater (or not less) than `ID_FROM`

Comment: I had it that way at first, but the OP's posting led me to believe the ID_To and ID_From could go either way.

Comment: this query returns 4 with his data for 1000, which is twice the number of pairs.

Comment: The OP wants to find pairs of **related** rows. There is no way (at least that I know of) that this can be accomplished using only `WHERE`.

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE :value > MIN(ID_From, ID_to) AND :value_1 < MAX(ID_From, ID_to)
```

both `:value` and `:value_1` gets the same value, of course.

Edit: there is no MIN / MAX in MySQL for this apparently so you need to do `IF(ID_from < ID_to, ID_From, ID_to)` if MIN:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE :value > IF(ID_From < ID_to, ID_From, ID_to) AND :value_1 < IF(ID_From < ID_to, ID_to, ID_From)
```

I kept the original as it's more understandable even if it's just pseudocode.

Comment: Even if you correct the pseudocode, it will not give the result wanted.